# Getting a token from SecurityContext in Spring Security 5

Tags: java, spring, security

I am trying to retrieve the value of an opaque token using spring security 5 so that I can pass that to another rest application to get other resources.
Here is my security configuration:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
```

public class OAuth2ResourceServerSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

```
@Value("${spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.opaque.introspection-uri}") String introspectionUri;
@Value("${spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.opaque.introspection-client-id}") String clientId;
@Value("${spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.opaque.introspection-client-secret}") String clientSecret;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // @formatter:off
    http
        .authorizeRequests((authorizeRequests) -> 
            authorizeRequests
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/message/**").hasAuthority("SCOPE_message:read")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/message/**").hasAuthority("SCOPE_message:write")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
        )
        .oauth2ResourceServer((oauth2ResourceServer) -> 
            oauth2ResourceServer
                .opaqueToken((opaqueToken) -> 
                    opaqueToken
                        .introspectionUri(this.introspectionUri)
                        .introspectionClientCredentials(this.clientId, this.clientSecret)
                )
        );
}
```

The controller looks like:

```
    @GetMapping("/")
public String index(@AuthenticationPrincipal(expression="subject") String subject) {
    return String.format("Hello, %s!", subject);
}
```

I want to access the token from within controller to forward that to the next service.

How can I do that?

Comment: Are you getting the token in the HTTP request header?

Comment: Yes. but I am new in spring security.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the HTTP header `Authorization` in Spring MVC using the following parameter in your controller method.

```java
@RequestHeader("Authorization") String header)
```

Note that they could be bearer tokens, and if they are indeed bearer tokens, you need to take a sub-string after `"Bearer "` (notice the space).